# U+000D ('controlCR') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

Tags: java, pdfbox

U+000D ('controlCR') is not available in this font Times-Roman encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

When I try to print my converted Html String on my pdf. When i try to do that the above error came

Comment: The problem is as described in the exception. There is no glyph in the font for `'\u000d'`.

Comment: See also https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#im-getting-javalangillegalargumentexception--is-not-available-in-this-fonts-encoding-winansiencoding you'll see that there is no CR glyph in WinAnsiEncoding. (Spoiler: not in any font, ever - enter "Movable type" into google images, you will never find a CR type)